# uploading file error using move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with the move_uploaded_file function. The problem is when I choose the image I want to upload, it doesn't move into the file i set.

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');
$path = 'images/';
if( $_FILES['image'])
{

$img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img;
// echo $img.$tmp.$final_image;
    if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions))
    {
     $path = $path.strtolower($final_image);

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path))
        {
            echo "<img src='$path' />";
            $insert = $mysqli->query("CALL sp_uploadImage('".$path."')");
        }
        else 
        {
        echo 'invalid';
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_FILES);
        }   
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run proper conditionals for your if statements and provide an alternate route in case it doesn't go as planned.

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');
$path = 'images/';
if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != ''){
// check if file name is set and not empty
$img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img;
    if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)){
        $path .= strtolower($final_image);
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)){
            echo "<img src='$path' />";
            $insert = $mysqli->query("CALL sp_uploadImage('".$path."')");
        }else {
            echo 'Failed to move Files';
        }   
    }else{
        echo 'Not a Valid Extension';
    }
}else{
    echo 'No Files Found';
}
?>
```

This way it will return the appropriate message and let you know what's going wrong.

Comment: The errors i got.
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/867835spadegaming.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xchangebet\cml\includes\upload_image.php on line 13

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpA2B1.tmp' to 'images/867835spadegaming.png' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xchangebet\cml\includes\upload_image.php on line 13
Failed to move Files

Comment: I'd say you probably have the wrong directory etc `images/`  is wrong and you need to reference it's proper location.